# Laravel using where clause on Views

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie on Laravel.

I can send data like that:

```
public function index()
{
      $InboxNew = Models\Inbox::where('read', false)->get();
      $InboxMarkedAsRead = Models\Inbox::where('read', true)->get();
      return view('dashboard.inbox', compact('InboxNew', 'InboxMarkedAsRead'));
}
```

I want to get data in view like that but gives some errors:

```
public function index()
{
        $Inbox = Models\Inbox::all();
        return view('dashboard.inbox', compact('Inbox'));
}
```

In view:

```
@if($Inbox->where('read', false)->get())
...
@endif
```

Comment: Whay you are trying to achieve in view?

Comment: I want to get rows if "read" columns value is "false"

Comment: Your first query is enought `$InboxNew = Models\Inbox::where('read', false)->get();` you just need a foteach loop in the view to get the collection data

Comment: Yeah, I know loops. I want to learn should I use where clause only in controller? Couldn't I use queries for seperate datas in view?

Comment: `Model::all()` and `Model::get()` will do the exact same thing. That give you a collection. So in blade, you just need to check _read_ status in a _if else_ condition under a foreach loop.

Comment: Use the first way. It's cleaner. Avoid doing SQL queries in the view. The view should only be responsible for presentation elements of your app

Answer (score 1):

Your controller :

```
public function index()
{
     $Inbox = Models\Inbox::all();
     return view('dashboard.inbox', compact('Inbox'));
}
```

In blade you can achieve your data like this way :

```
@foreach($inbox as $query)
 @if($query->read == false)
   //
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you have already called `all()` method on the `Models\Inbox`. What `all()` do is to simply call the `get()` method on model without applying any conditions.

You either need to define only a model (via **`query()`** method:

```
// Controller
public function index()
    {
        $Inbox = Models\Inbox::query();
        return view('dashboard.inbox', compact('Inbox'));
    }
```

and fetch it later with `where` clauses In view:

```
@if($Inbox->where('read', false)->get())
...
@endif
```

**OR**

You can do it in a cleaner way, which is to fetch the data in controller and use the view only to show the data

You either need to define only a model (via **`query()`** method:

```
// Controller
public function index()
    {
        $Inbox = Models\Inbox::where('read', false)->get();
        return view('dashboard.inbox', compact('Inbox'));
    }
```

and fetch it later with `where` clauses In view:

```
@if($Inbox)
...
@endif
```

**PS:** To check if a record exists, use `exists()` method instead of `get()` e.g `$Inbox->exists()`